# Constant in a key value pair

Tags: javascript, c#, session-variables

I am doing a post to a Action in MVC 5 from Javascript in order to set a variable in the session:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController"), { key: "myKey", value: returnValue });
```

Where return value comes back from a service and the string "myKey" is what the value in session is stored as:

So MyAction looks like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void MyAction(string key, string value)
    {
        Session[key] = value;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see why you have to store it in a variable in the first place. This should do the trick.

```
[HttpPost]
    public void MyAction(string value)
    {
        Session["myKey"] = value;
    }
```